# screen returns [screen is terminating], but never terminates

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, gnu-screen

I recently ran into an issue on my Ubuntu 12.10 server that I can't seem to find a solution for. From my server I run a couple of Minecraft servers on different ports, usually to start the servers I would use the following command.

```
screen -S minecraft java -Xmx2048M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui
```

There was never a problem until recently, as soon as I run the command it outputs

```
[screen is terminating]
```

No matter what privileges/account I'm under, sudo, root, a normal user, none of them. All return the same thing. I've tried rebooting the entire server, wiping all screens `screen -wipe`. I've also tried listing all the screens thinking that it would expose the screen that is still "terminating", but all it returns is `No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-user.`

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you see the message, it's likely the screen has already terminated. It doesn't update the message to reflect the fact it has already terminated itself. The likely cause for this is that java is instantly exiting, and you should run `java -Xmx2048M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui` in the same directory to find out why. Typically when you run screen with a command the moment the command exits screen exits as well.

Comment: Thanks, it was just a little permissions error, fixed it and its working flawlessly now.